# How to filter date by range in Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to filter the column date at my table. I was draw my table using Datatable. The data from my table was sent from server.

I already try some suggestions based on google search, stackoverflow, and datatable forum. But it didn't work.

And i don't know why the afnFiltering function didn't. I alrdy check it with console.log but it didn't print.

Here is my work so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-2">Pilih Tanggal Mulai</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="tanggal_mulai" name="tanggal_mulai" class="form-control tanggal">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Date -->
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-2">Pilih Tanggal Akhir</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="tanggal_akhir" name="tanggal_akhir" class="form-control tanggal">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="tbl-reporting" class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>ID Pekerjaan</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Alasan Approve/Reject</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $("#tbl-reporting").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/method') ?>"
             dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'print'
            ],
        });
    //datepicker for start date
    $("#tanggal_mulai").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        onSelect: function (date) {
            minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            table.draw()
        }
    }).keyup(function () {
        minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        table.draw();
    });
    //datepicker for end date
    $("#tanggal_akhir").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        onSelect: function (date) {
            maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            table.draw()
        }
    }).keyup(function () {
        maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        table.draw();
    });
    minDateFilter = "";
    maxDateFilter = "";
    //this function didn't run
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.afnFiltering.push(
        function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
            alert('AAAAA');
            if (typeof aData._date === 'undefined') {
                aData._date = new Date(aData[2]).getTime(); //aData[2] because it's in 3rd column
            }
            if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
                if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
                if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    );
});
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      1,
      "111",
      "13-05-2020 09:43:51",
      null,
      "Approve</span></a> Reject </span></a>"
    ],
    [
      2,
      "110",
      "12-05-2020 07:47:13",
      null,
      "Approve </span></a> Reject </span></a>"
    ],
    [
      3,
      "109",
      "11-05-2020 07:00:43",
      null,
      "Approve </span></a> Reject </span></a>"
    ]
  ],      
}
```

The date column value is in `d-m-Y H:i:s` format from PHP, i want to filter it by javascript with `dd-mm-yyyy` format.
This fiddle is my inspiration http://jsfiddle.net/41jr8xgo/5/

Please enlighten me. Been stuck for 2 weeks.
Up up up Up

Comment: Can you please share your code as well? Thanks!

Comment: Done. I was modified it @norbitrial